# How to redirect to current path without format (.json, .xml -> .html)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have an unpermitted user trying to request a JSON or CSV file how can I redirect them to the same path but without the format.

```
  def some_before_filter
    if !current_admin_user.can_download_resources? and request.format != "text/html"
      request.format = "text/html"
    end
  end
```

This directs to the root_path, not the current request without format.

RoR 3.2

Comment: try redirect_to :back

Comment: Can you post the two URLs, json and html format? Think about it, when someone tries to access a resource through `/posts/1.json` and you don't offer json, then they should get a 404. Or, if they set the format through a header I would sent a `406 - Not Acceptable` status to the client

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and tried to implement following code and it worked. you may also use `format: :html` if you want to retain html at the end of url. I don't know whether the following is the correct way, because I just guessed the following code and it worked. I'm using rails 4.2

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.any { redirect_to format: nil }
      end
```